# Как перемешать случайным образом HashMap?

Tags: kotlin

Как можно перемешать HashMap? Ни Random() ни shuffled не работает.

```
private val listChannels:HashMap<Int,String> = HashMap()
    
        init {
            listChannels[1] = "Первый"
            listChannels[2] = "МАТЧ!"
            listChannels[3] = "НТВ"
            listChannels[4] = "5"
            listChannels[5] = "Россия К"
            listChannels[6] = "Россия 24"
            listChannels[7] = "Карусель"
            listChannels[8] = "ОТР"
            listChannels[9] = "ТВЦ"
            listChannels[10] = "РенТВ"
            listChannels[11] = "СПАС"
            listChannels[12] = "СТС"
            listChannels[13] = "Домашний"
            listChannels[14] = "ТВ3"
            listChannels[15] = "Пятница"
            listChannels[16] = "Звезда"
            listChannels[17] = "МИР"
            listChannels[18] = "МУЗ"
        }
    
        fun getRandomChannels():HashMap<Int,String> {
            listChannels.entries.shuffled().first()
            return listChannels
        }
```

Comment: HashMap не является коллекцией и его элементы не упорядочены. Упорядочить или перемешать элементы HashMap невозможно. [Переформулируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1463672/edit) ваш вопрос или задайте [новый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Если вам важен порядок, то можете использовать список из пар `List<Pair<Int, String>>` вместо `Map<Int, String>`.